# Writing huge 2D vectors to text file too slow

Tags: c++, performance, file, csv, vectors

I have 10 large (34 million cell) 2D gridded vectors storing doubles. When written they are over 200 MB in size. I use an `ofstream` object to write them to a text file (.csv format), one element at a time, using two for loops (one for my rows, one for my columns). They take way to long to write. Is there a faster way to write from these vectors?

(I am using Visual Studio 2012.)

```
// Resizing of vectors
flowDirGrid.resize(rows, std::vector<double>(cols, NODATA));

// Do some processing
....

// Outputting processed data
ofstream outfile3("FlowDir.dat");
if(!outfile3.good())
    return;

for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)        
    {
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            if(elevation[i][j]!=NODATA)
                outfile3 << flowDirGrid[i][j]<<" ";
            else
                outfile3 << NODATA<<" ";
        }
        outfile3 << std::endl;
    }

outfile3.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The output-writing code should reside in a function that takes two parameters: the `flowDirGrid` and a filename.

Don't omit braces on multi-line conditionals.  It's a filthy habit, and someday you will contribute to a coding accident [like this](https://gotofail.com).

A performance problem is outputting `std::endl` at the end of every line, which causes a flush.  Output `'\n'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your conditional:

```
        if(elevation[i][j]!=NODATA)
            outfile3 << flowDirGrid[i][j]<<" ";
        else
            outfile3 << NODATA<<" ";
```

I rewrite as a ternary

```
 outfile3 << elevation[i][j] == NODATA ? NODATA : flowDirGrid[i][j] << " ";
```

The ternary poses importance on the fact that only the value changes. `if` should be used when also the action changes.

Comment: Will this really speed up the code?  What's the typical performer improvement?

Comment: @traggatmot This may speed up the code a tiny bit but mainly enhances clarity.

Comment: That's funny. I find ternaries more confusing.

Comment: @traggatmot The result of a ternary can only be a value. You may find anything (an expression) in an if block. If the action (print) is the same, a ternary is more limited and therefore more easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth considering using `std::basic_streambuf` as apposed to `std::basic_ostream`. You'd need to do the `double` formatting yourself, but this may still be quicker. Here's an example which shows how to do this for a single `std::vector<double>`, it should be fairly easy to generalise to a 2D version.

```
// streambuf.cpp

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

void write_basic_ostream(const std::vector<double>& v, std::ofstream& of)
{
    std::copy(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<double> {of, " "});
}

void write_basic_streambuf(const std::vector<double>& v, std::ofstream& of)
{
    std::string str {};
    str.reserve(v.size() * (1 + sizeof(double)));

    for (const auto& e : v) {
        str += std::to_string(e);
        str += " ";
    }

    std::copy(str.cbegin(), str.cend() - 1, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(of));
}

int main()
{
    std::size_t n {10000000};

    std::default_random_engine generator {};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution {0.0, 1.0};

    std::vector<double> v(n);
    std::generate_n(v.begin(), n, [&generator, &distribution] { return distribution(generator); });

    std::ofstream of1 {"/Users/you/test_basic_ostream.txt"};
    std::ofstream of2 {"/Users/you/test_basic_streambuf.txt"};

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    write_basic_ostream(v, of1);

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start);

    std::cout << "basic_ostream: "  << duration.count() << std::endl;

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    write_basic_streambuf(v, of2);

    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start);

    std::cout << "write_basic_streambuf: "   << duration.count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Some quick benchmarks has `write_basic_ostream` about 20% slower than `write_basic_streambuf` on my system (`g++ streambuf.cpp -std=c++14 -O3 -o test`).